# Oracle/mySQL database

Tags: database, database-design, many-to-many, data-modeling

I'm kinda new in databases and I need to solve this one:

```
client(NAME, CITY, STREET, NUMBER, BALANCE, CLIENT_CODE);
order(ORDER_NUMBER, CLIENT_CODE, PROVIDER_NAME, FUEL, QTY, DATE);
provider(PROVIDER_NAME, PROVIDER_ADRESS, FUEL_CODE, PRICE, STOCK);
fuel(FUEL_CODE, FUEL_NAME);
```

I've already tried (and succeeded I guess) to create an ALTER TABLE for provider and fuel named provider_fuel in order to solve many-to-many relationship, but I don't have any idea how I could create a connection between order and provider.

I've changed the entities like this:

```
provider(PROVIDER_ID, PROVIDER_ADRESS);
fuel(FUEL_CODE, FUEL_NAME);
provider_fuel(ID_ENTRY, ID_PROVIDER, ID_FUEL, PRICE, STOCK).
```

Is that even ok? If so, how can I make connections between all those entities in my database?

I have to mention that my app should allow clients to place orders from providers who have their specific fuels, prices and so on.

Comment: Try to be consistent with your column names - id_provider in provider_fuel would be better if consistent with provider_id in provider.  Also change provider_name in orders to provider_id and hey presto relationship established..(with a join)

Comment: And note that 'order' is a reserved word in MySQL, rendering it a poor choice as a table/column identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following table layouts:

```
address(ID_ADDRESS, CITY, STREET, NUMBER);

client(ID_CLIENT, NAME, ID_ADDRESS);

client_order(ID_CLIENT_ORDER, ID_CLIENT, RECEIVED_DATE);

client_order_detail(ID_CLIENT_ORDER_DETAIL, ID_CLIENT_ORDER, ID_PROVIDER, ID_PRODUCT,
                    ORDER_QTY, STATUS, DELIVERED_DATE);  -- Status in ('OPEN', 'DELIVERED')

provider(ID_PROVIDER, NAME, ID_ADDRESS);

product(ID_PRODUCT, PRODUCT_NAME);

provider_product(ID_PROVIDER, ID_PRODUCT, PRICE, STOCK_QTY);
```

You can, if you like, expand this. For example, a provider might have multiple locations from which product can be supplied, in which case you'd need to re-work the single PROVIDER table into something like

```
PROVIDER(ID_PROVIDER, NAME)

PROVIDER_PRODUCT(ID_PROVIDER, ID_PRODUCT, PRICE)

PROVIDER_ADDRESS(ID_PROVIDER_ADDRESS, ID_PROVIDER, ID_ADDRESS)
```

and then rework PROVIDER_PRODUCT as

```
PROVIDER_ADDRESS_PRODUCT(ID_PROVIDER_ADDRESS, ID_PRODUCT, STOCK_QTY)
```

I suppose it's also possible that the price a provider charges might depend on the location from which it's shipped so you might need to change the model to accommodate that. The point is that there are many different ways to do this, and it depends very much on the requirements you have.

### EDIT

To obtain the total value of an order using the tables above you'd use a query such as:

```
SELECT co.ID_CLIENT_ORDER, SUM(cod.ORDER_QTY * pp.PRICE) AS ORDER_TOTAL_VALUE
  FROM CLIENT_ORDER co
  INNER JOIN CLIENT_ORDER_DETAIL cod
    ON cod.ID_CLIENT_ORDER = co.ID_CLIENT_ORDER
  INNER JOIN PROVIDER_PRODUCT pp
    ON pp.ID_PROVIDER = cod.ID_PROVIDER AND
       pp.ID_PRODUCT = cod.ID_PRODUCT
  GROUP BY co.ID_CLIENT_ORDER
  ORDER BY co.ID_CLIENT_ORDER
```

Comment: Just to point out that 'order' is a reserved word in MySQL, rendering it a poor choice as a table/column identifier.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have burned my brain for two weeks in order to make this kind of layout. One more question tho. How can I show the total value for an order based on the price from provider_product and the order_qty from order_details?

Comment: @Strawberry - good point, and fixed by changing the table name to CLIENT_ORDER (as opposed to PURCHASE_ORDER, which is a standard business term for a document issued to authorize purchase of a good or service from another business)

Answer (score -1):

You can put id_provider in order table and get the provider details by the id .For ex

```
Select *,p.price,p.fuel_code from order as o join provider as p on o.id_provider=p.id
```

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to the Oracle database world!

You can make connections between tables or views using *JOIN* structure.

In your example, you can connect your tables like this:

```
SELECT od.* FROM order od, provider pd WHERE od.provider_name=pd.provider_name
```

Or you can write it like this. It's up to your style. But I prefer the first one.

```
SELECT od.* FROM order od INNER JOIN provider pd ON od.provider_name=pd.provider_name
```

But it's always better using NUMBER type columns in joins. So I suggest, create provider_id (NUMBER type) on 2 tables and join them.

There are 5 main types (INNER, OUTER, FULL, LEFT, RIGHT) of joins in SQL. Each of them provides different things.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly your database represents a market place where a client can buy different kinds of fuels from providers. So far you have used natural keys:

- A client has some login code that identifys them (client_code).
- A provider is identified by their name. Do you want this? That would mean a provider address stays constant and cannot change. That may or may not be desired. If the company JACOB'S FUELSHOP INC changes to THE FUELSHOP INC, do you want to treat it as the same company or a different one?
- You also generate order numbers. Do you want them unique in your database, or per client or per provider? The order table's key would accordingly be either just order_number or order_number + client_code or order_number + provider_name.

Now you don't want to have one provider only sell one type of fuel, but various types. You introduce a bridge table. But in the same step you introduce technical IDs. Do you want to use technical IDs instead of natural keys?

You have provider(PROVIDER_ID, PROVIDER_ADRESS) where the provider's name is either missing or included in the address. This allows you to change the name later. But remember that you may want to store the name then with every order, as you may want to reprint it later or just say whether you placed the order with the legal company JACOB'S FUELSHOP INC or THE FUELSHOP INC. Technical IDs are fine, but you must remember to still keep unique constraints on the natural keys and think about consequences as the one just mentioned.

As to the fuel price: You are storing the current fuel price, but you are not storing the price when ordered. Add the price to the orders table.

As to your question: Order and provider are already linked by provider_name in the original design. In the new design you've introduced the provider_id. If you want to use this instead, put provider_id in the orders table. As mentioned, you may or may not want the provider name in that table, too.

Comment: I didn't like the fact that order and provider did have PROVIDER_NAME instead of PROVIDER_ID so I changed that to simplify things out. And for provider and fuel I want to use technical ID's because I want my fuels, for example, to be found as 101, 202, 303 id's or smth like that. I only had this problem of layouts, but I've received an answer on that. Now I have a problem finding the total value of an order based on qty from order and price from provider_fuel.

Comment: As mentioned, it's okay to work with technical IDs. I agree they are easy to work with. Only remember that you still want the provider name unique in the provider table (i.e. you still need a constraint on that column) and you may need the name in the order table too for aforementioned reasons. And I suggested you add the price to the order table, for prices can change. You want the price that was valid for that order, so store it there. Getting the order price is simple then: it's order quantity x order price. Or you can just store the total order price. Then you don't even have to calculate.

Comment: I know the mathematical look, but how should it look in oracle/mySQL. I'm more interested in SELECT form and how can I select the exact price from a specific type of fuel sold by a specific provider. Smth like p.ID_PROVIDER=o.ID_PROVIDER and p.ID_FUEL=o.ID_FUEL? As I said, I'm new into this world.

Comment: I said the price you ordered the fuel for belongs in the order table. So it's something along the lines of `select qty * price from orders where order_number = 123`.

Comment: My bad. Thank you very much!